# Merge two jacococ.exec files

Tags: java, jacoco

My requirement is to create one .csv files with code coverage. I use jacococ library.Here I run my test cases in two server instances where two jacoco.exec files are created. I want to merge them into one. How to do this ?
Part of the pom.xml is given below.

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>merge-all-jacoco</id>
                        <goals><goal>merge</goal></goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>merged.exec</destFile>
                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>

                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.exec</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```